# AngularJS Directives - can you set a template to data from an AJAX call?

Tags: ajax, angularjs

In Angular is it possible to grab data from an AJAX call, and translate it into HTML that is put into a Directive template?

Here is a Pseudo Example below:

```
 App.directive('aDirective', function (){

     var getTemplate = function() {
            var template = '';

        //Make Ajax call here
        ...

        angular.forEach(content_from_ajax, function (data) {
                template += '<li>data</li>';
            });

            return template;
        }

           return {
            restrict: "E",
            template: getTemplate();
          };
    });
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
<a-directive></a-directive>
</ul>
```

This example would show an arbitrary length list.

How would I go on doing this?

Comment: Though theoretically possible, this is not the intended way of using angular. You would be better off using an existing template with an ng-repeat directive.

Answer (score 1):

Just because you are writing a directive, you shouldn't forget how normal Angular things, like templating based on data, are done.

In other words, you seem to receive an array of data from the backend, and you want to render the data in a list. Isn't it the perfect job for an `ng-repeat`?

```
App.directive('aDirective', function (AjaxService){
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    template: '<li ng-repeat="item in content_from_ajax">{{item}}</li>',
    link: function(scope){
       // AjaxService here is a standin to how you get data from the backend
       AjaxService.getData()
                  .then(function(data){
                     scope.content_from_ajax = data;
                  });
    }
});
```

The `ng-repeat` would just work normally - i.e. iterate over the data and produce a template.

Also, `template` or `templateUrl` properties of the directive definition object do not support async operations, so your entire idea of asynchronously fetching a template in `getTemplate` and then using the result with `template: getTemplate()` would not have worked.